# How can I add my business to the merchant list on the Monero website?

Tags: merchants, getmonero-website

Is there an easy way to make a listing request?

If I am familiar with GitHub, how should I go about doing it myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Easy method:**

- Visit the [merchant page](https://getmonero.org/getting-started/merchants)
- Use the [open issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/issues) link at bottom of page
- Login to and/or create a GitHub account
- Click [new](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/issues/new)
- Enter your merchant information
- Click `submit new issue`
- Track your request [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/issues)

**Do it yourself method:**

- Visit the GitHub for the [monero website](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site)
- Login to GitHub
- Make a fork of the site
- Click `data`
- Click `merchants.yml`
- Click `edit`
- Add your merchant information in a format consistent with the existing listings
- Click `create a new branch for this commit and start a pull request`
- Click `propose file change`
- track your [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/pulls)