# For newcomers to the Monero community, what can we do to help the project?

Tags: monero-community, new-user

There are a lot of newcomers into the Monero community and I am sure many are interested in helping out where they can.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Documenting (helping here on stack exchange is actually quite helpful, but helping to write tutorials to do stuff is also useful)
- Testing (know how to compile some code? then it helps for others to test out builds, or run software on various version so catch any errors that sliup through)
- Donations (not just to monero devs, but also for bounties in the forum funding section, or if theres a feature you're passionate about, you could get it posted)
- Run a node (secure the network, help keep Monero decentralised, it's simple to do, and only requires some bandwidth)
- Mine (it's still possible to mine, even on a cpu, it you have some spare hardware, you are actively adding to it's decentralisation)
- If you have an IT or CS background and can code, go to #monero-dev on freenode and ask around to see if anything needs doing, or simply go to the official [repo](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core) and see what issues need help.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the excellent suggestions provided by [ferretinjapan](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1648/7), there are a few simple tasks that have been described here on SE.

Specifically help is needed with:

- [Moneropedia](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/how-can-i-edit-a-moneropedia-definition-or-add-a-new-one) could use many more terms and definitions and should be updated over time as Monero continues to develop.
- [Creating merchant listings](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/how-can-i-add-my-business-to-the-merchant-list-on-the-monero-website) on the Monero website for new businesses that accept Monero. You do not need to be the business owner to do this.

Answer (score 9):

Document your journey into Monero and give feedback to the developers on usability and issues you encountered while learning how to use it.  The community needs to come together to make it easy for new people to learn and use Monero for it to be successful.

Answer (score 3):

One simple thing you could do is to find videos on youtube about Monero and like them, put some comments. It will help spread the word.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to help out, you can always just donate to the project and call it a day. But if you want to go further, ask where your own strengths meet the needs of this project, and then act accordingly. I asked that same question a few months ago, realized I was good with blogging/media, so I created an educational website about Monero.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest the size of the Monero community is very very small in the grand scheme of things. Even beyond that, bitcoin itself is still a very niche thing in the wider world.  Talk to the friends you know who might be interested in this kind of thing.
Take the reddit having only ~6,000 users for example -that is growing around 20 ppl a day which would double the community size within a year. That's a lot of extra developers/enthusiasts/users who can be involved.